# Edit Profile and Token creation

Tags: artifactory

When entering the "Edit Profile" menu, an error pops from the top: "Password Incorrect"
If you press the "Generate API Token" button, an error pops from the top: "You are not authorized to view this page".

This happens to all users, even to admins, which I'm one of.

I upgraded to latest available version, to see if it has any affects on the problem. Didn't help.

Were using the Pro license (not ProX) and version is 7.24.3
Default installation with Derby as the DB.

We have Jira/Crowd integration but this has worked well for a few months so cant exactly pinpoint when it started.

Any self debugging actions, as i cant open a support ticket when its the Pro edition

Answer (score 1):

So the issue has been resolved but im not entirely sure what was the reason.
I basically re-entered all the same crowd connector details , and it probably cleared something that even an upgrade and server restart didnt fix, but its back to normal and no error messages now.

technology is wierd ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Arie Just to confirm are there any special characters used in the password like german characters or any other such characters? Can you create a dummy user with a normal password (use @ as a special character to test) and check if the issue comes up? If not, edit the password of this user and include the actual special character to test it out.

Comment: I cant really say. We have about 2000 jira users in crowd and that one sync with our AD but we dont provide SSO, you still have to login. So what ever characters AD allows thats what we have potentially.
I would imagine if bad characters were involved that it would affect specific users, not everyone, independent on their role in the system. Plus i cant say what would have triggered it occurred before the upgrade to latest version and after, so its not something stuck in memory for example.

My own PW doenst have any "funny" characters and it happens to me as well.

Comment: Arie, I see, but can you confirm if this issue happens only with crowd users or Artifactory internal users are also impacted?

Comment: Interesting, in local artifactory, for a user that i created i dont see this issue. Then again we dont use any local users, and i cant simulate a new user in crowd as its bound to our AD.

Comment: That's good to know.. can you confirm if the password used for the internal user is kinda similar to your password?